# Set SQL alias value

Tags: sql, sql-scripts

Is there a way to set value of alias `isApprover` by checking on another column by or e.g. (if the `Control.ApproverID` or `Process.TApprover` has a value then set the alias with true value)

Here are the two columns:

```
cast(case 
        when max(isnull(Process.TApprover,0)) = :MemberId 
           then 1 
           else 0 
     end as bit) as isApprover,

cast(case 
        when max(isnull(Control.ApproverID,0)) = :MemberId 
           then 1 
           else 0 
     end as bit) as isApprover,
```

Comment: Whats wrong with your query?

Comment: i need to return "isApprover" alias with true value if one of columns has a true value.
is what i wrote above will work ?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: @marc_s looks like sql server isn't it?